# JavaScript: setting direction of css change on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, mouseover

In the following code, ([see example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyxJ7/11/)), if you mouseover the green, the height of the two red boxes will change, but the height expands down. Is there a way to make the height expand upwards?

css:

```
.one{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 110px; 
    top: 0px; 
    background: green;
}

.two {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 70px; 
    top: 40px; 
    background: red; 
    height: 25px; 
    font-size: 25px;
}

.three {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 200px;
    top: 40px; 
    background: red; 
    height: 25px; 
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="one">15,000,000</div>
<div class="two">700</div>
<div class="three">800</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.one').mouseover(function(){
   $('.two, .three').css('height','50px');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.two, .three').css('height', '25px');
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just alter the `top` of the boxes as well:

```
$('.one').mouseover(function(){
   $('.two, .three').css({ height : '50px', top: '15px'});
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.two, .three').css({ height : '25px', top: '40px'});
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wyxJ7/12/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
http://jsfiddle.net/Gbwjj/

Its more of a CSS issue than a JavaScript one

Answer (score 0):

You can use change the 'top' css attribute at the same time so that the user perceives it as the height expanding upwards.  Here's an example using animate().

```
 $('.one').mouseover(function(){
    $('.two, .three').animate({
        height:"50px",
        top:"-=25"
    });
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.two, .three').animate({
        height:"25px",
        top:"+=25"
    });
  });
```